# Select data from two related columns in MySql

Tags: mysql

table proyectos has two related columns, **id_pro** and **id_padre**

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `proyectos` (
  `id_pro` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ot_padre` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `nom_pro` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_pro`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `proyectos` (`id_pro`, `ot_padre`, `nom_pro`) VALUES
  ('1', '0', 'Proyecto 1'),
  ('2', '0', 'Proyecto 2'),
  ('3', '0', 'Proyecto 3'),
  ('4', '3', 'Proyecto hijo 1'),
  ('5', '3', 'Proyecto hijo 2');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `servicios` (
  `id_ser` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_pro` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `nom_ser` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_ser`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `servicios` (`id_ser`, `id_pro`, `nom_ser`) VALUES
  ('1', '1', 'Servicio a'),
  ('2', '1', 'Servicio b'),
  ('3', '3', 'Servicio c'),
  ('4', '3', 'Servicio d'),
  ('5', '4', 'Servicio e'),
  ('6', '5', 'Servicio e');
```

How can obtain all data from servicios with id_pro 3, and also all service with id_padre 3?

EDIT**

expected output

```
id_ser |  id_pro |   nom_ser   |
3      |  3      |  Servicio c |
4      |  3      |  Servicio d |
5      |  4      |  Servicio e |
6      |  5      |  Servicio f |
```

schema and query
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a1e0dc/1/0

Comment: What should the desired result look like? Edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @Strawberry edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an `INNER` join of the tables:

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM servicios s INNER JOIN proyectos p
ON p.id_pro = s.id_pro 
WHERE 3 IN (p.id_pro, p.ot_padre)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8e11b58a1a04ec8bf8a5ea6ffdb08680).
Results:

> | id_ser | id_pro | nom_ser |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 3 | 3 | Servicio c |
> | 4 | 3 | Servicio d |
> | 5 | 4 | Servicio e |
> | 6 | 5 | Servicio f |

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Servicios 
WHERE id_pro = 3
OR id_pro IN 
    (SELECT id_pro 
    FROM Proyectos 
    WHERE id_padre = 3)
```

Outputs:

```
id_ser  id_pro  nom_ser
3   3   Servicio c
4   3   Servicio d
5   4   Servicio e
```

Comment: `DISTINCT *` is either an oxymoron or a tautology, depending on your point of view

Comment: It's useless in ALL cases.

Comment: If `*` and `DISTINCT *` ever return anything other than the same thing, then you would have grave problems with your schema.

Comment: Even with your modified SQL Fiddle, my statement should give you the desired result...

@Strawberry So the "all" statement was an exaggeration. You could have just saved us some time and wrote this directly rather than trolling around ;)

Comment: `my statement should give you the desired result` well, does it?

Comment: Force of habit, I guess

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that you're actually after this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM servicios
 WHERE id_pro = 3
 UNION
SELECT s.*
  FROM servicios s
  JOIN proyectos p
    ON p.id_pro = s.id_pro
 WHERE p.ot_padre = 3;
```

(There are various ways of writing this, including a LEFT JOIN with COALESCE)